# How do I htaccess redirect index.html to index.php and index.php to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently changed my index.html to index.php - I want to be able to do a redirect to reflect this, and then also a rewrite that forces foo.com/index.php to just be foo.com/ and have it access the .php file.

I also have a separate site i.e. bar.com located in a subdirectory under foo.com that I want to remain unaffected.

This is what I had, which results in a redirect loop:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.html?$ /index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RedirectMatch` directive matches *after* the internal redirect that takes the `/` request and redirects it to `/index.html`, then it get put through the URL-file mapping pipeline again and thus matches your redirect directive.

You can try including a:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to prevent this automatic internal redirect. You should also use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` match with the `index.html` file like you're doing with `index.php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1index.php [R=301,L]
```

Or you can bypass index.php entirely:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Exactly what I wanted/needed. Thanks a million!